# Why is Tmin 1 bit more than Tmax

Tags: c

Correct me if I am wrong but on a 64 bit machine in c, these are the values for tmax and min.

```
int tmax = 2147483647;
int tmin = -2147483648;
```

I was wondering, why  tmin is 1 bit more than tmax.

Comment: Read about [two's complement](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=two%27s+complement)

Comment: Consider just 4 bits rather than 32. With 4 bits you have a total of 16 values: 8 "positive" (0, 1, 2, ..., 7) and 8 negative (-1, -2, -3, ..., -8)... `-8` (`0b1000`) is not 1 bit more than `7` (`0b0111`)

Comment: There is an even number of values available, because the storage size is a power of two. So if there is one 'zero' value, there can't the same number of positive values as there are negative values (unless you make one value invalid, for example to mean "not set").

Comment: @some systems have also `-0` and `INT_MAX == -INT_MIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of zero.

The negative numbers that a 32-bit twos-complement `int` can represent are −1 through −2,147,483,648.
The *non*negative numbers that a 32-bit twos-complement `int` can represent are 0 through 2,147,483,647.

There are exactly 2<sup>31</sup> of each.

(Also, a terminological nitpick: 2,147,483,648 is *one* more than 2,147,483,647, not *one bit* more.  One bit more would be 4,294,967,294—twice as much.)